# How Can I use SLDS system in my Salesforce Devloper Blog for styling? How?

Tags: slds

How Can I use SLDS system in my Salesforce Devloper Blog for styling? How?
I have blog where I keep posting about Salesforce development. I want to give look and fill of SLDS for that blog.

Comment: yes. Include js/css and other assets. Do not forget to check license

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can, you can use it as you would any other style/css static resource. The SLDS is available for downloading at:

https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/downloads/

and the documentation for using it at:

https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/